# What does the np.poly1d function do in this program?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have to understand how the function poly1d() works, especially if I delete a element.
Here an example:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
pol =  np.poly1d(x)
print(pol)
for i in range(x.size):
    pol = np.poly1d(np.delete(x,i))
    print(pol)
```

Output:

```
   3     2
1 x + 2 x + 3 x + 4
   2
2 x + 3 x + 4
   2
1 x + 3 x + 4
   2
1 x + 2 x + 4
   2
1 x + 2 x + 3
```

Whats happening here and why? The pol is changing, but it doesn't delete the value at the index i.

Comment: Why do you specify `True` in the loop calls, but not the original?  That parameter makes a big change in how `poly1d` uses the first argument.  In the first call you specify the coefficients, in the subsequent ones you specify the roots.

Comment: @hpaulj If I change True to False I have the same problem, with other values. So at the moment their is nor reason for true, because the problem did not change.

Comment: What are you expecting?  I demonstrated your code without that `True`, and results are obvious (to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [301]: x = np.array([1,2,3,4]) 
     ...: pol =  np.poly1d(x) 
     ...: print(pol) 
     ...: for i in range(x.size): 
     ...:     pol = np.poly1d(np.delete(x,i)) 
     ...:     print(pol) 
     ...:                                                                       
   3     2
1 x + 2 x + 3 x + 4
   2
2 x + 3 x + 4
   2
1 x + 3 x + 4
   2
1 x + 2 x + 4
   2
1 x + 2 x + 3
```

This displays a poly with [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [1,3,4] and [1,2,3] coefficients.  What's mysterious about this?